# bootstrap modal in background not usable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

i use bootstrap on my website and i have modals which were working perfectly.
Since yesterday, my modals are not usable anymore. The grey background which should cover the area around the modal is now on the whole page. Thus, it's impossible to click on the modal or to use it. I have to reload the page manually.

Here is a screenshot : 
[image]

I use the last version of Bootstrap (3.3.7). Even with the most basic modal exemple from official Bootstrap documentation it does the same :

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know where it could come from, since it's a bought template i didn't create myself.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: it works well, it's something wrong in your CSS: http://www.bootply.com/dpjyW2oQff

Comment: I will try to redownload bootstrap then